# Multiple kernels in Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, linux, kernel, enthought, canopy

I previously worked with the EPD Python distribution using its Qt-console, where one of the most useful features was easily having multiple kernels in multiple tabs, when doing several calculations simultaneously.

I recently got the "new" Enthought Canopy, which somehow tries to emulate MatLab, which might not be bad perse. Here comes the problem: How do I get multiple tabs with separated kernels with Canopy?

For completeness, I am running Canopy 1.1.0 on Ubuntu-Gnome 13.04.

Answer (score 2):

The *Canopy GUI application* does not yet support multiple kernels. However, just like with EPD, you can run QtConsole, including using its multiple kernel capabilities, from a Canopy User Python command line.

To do this quickly:

`~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/ipython qtconsole`

Long-term, the easiest way to run Canopy User Python may be to make it your default `python`, using the Canopy preferences dialog. Details at:

http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

Comment: Thanks. This means that there is no simple way of using Canopy in the same way as EPD. Do you know when multiple kernels will be available for Canopy? Frankly speaking, I do not understand how one can exclude such an essential feature.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your response earlier. You are missing the heart of my response. I have edited it for emphasis and added detail. Bottom line: what you could do with EPD, you can do with Canopy.