# Handling multiple python distributions

Tags: python, linux, qt, matplotlib, enthought

I guess I am partly responsible for the mess, but I can imagine that several users might have similar problems. I installed several python versions/distributions on my new Ubuntu-Gnome 13.04, which comes with python3.3 (0), including

1. python2.7.5
2. PyLab (python2.7.3)
3. EPD-python2.7.3
4. Canopy-1.1.0 (??)
5. Anaconda 1.6.1 (python2.7.5)

My main purpose for doing so was to get a python environment with the functionality of the Qt-console, which previously worked perfectly with the EPD-python distribution.

I now encountered several problems with basically all of the above. "Plain" pythons, such as 0, 1 and 2 do not offer the functionality I desire, while the others have their problems by their own, and I hope somebody knows to help here:

**3:** When starting the Qt-console shipped with the EPD-python distribution (installation worked perfectly fine), it cannot load the graphics package `Matplotlib` anymore, telling me

`ImportError: Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8
Error initializing pylab, pylab mode will not be active`

Manually importing does also not work. Why doesn't it work by itself as a stand-alone version, but requires a python version which is higher than the one EPD installed.

**4:** Cannot figure out how to use Canopy within a Qt-console or use the GUI for multi-tasking, i.e. multiple kernels. I previously addressed this issue here: [Multiple kernels in Enthought Canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572379/multiple-kernels-in-enthought-canopy).

**5:** Anaconda should also have an Qt-console. But after installing it, I cannot find any application relating to it. The only thing I can do is to run it in the terminal, either as normal python or ipython (the same I can do with EPD-python as well). It seems that this is not the full functionality of Anaconda, but I might be wrong here.

Any help is appreciated!!

BTW, can one make all these python communicate with each other and make them somehow "harmonise"?

Comment: sounds like a mess.  You should probably look into using virtualenv.

Comment: I just found out part of the solution: for **3**, the solution can be found here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22096567-Ubuntu-IPython-pylab-not-working

Comment: check the backend setting in `matplotlibrc`

Comment: Are you using the ubuntu package manager or installing all of this by hand?  What do you mean by 'PyLab'?  That _should_ be a module in `matplotlib`

Comment: I installed all of this by hand. By PyLab I mean the working environment. It came twice, once with the EPD-distribution (same problem as **3**, which is a **solved**, as described in the above link) and once with the Qt-console (from here: http://ipython.org/), which I tried to get manually, but failed. Basically it is working now. At the moment, I am just wondering if there should be an separate application for the Anaconda distribution somewhere, like for the Enthought distros. I can only run it in the terminal for now.

Comment: Just posted a solution on a similar problem to 3 for `Matplotlib`, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956628/got-libatk-1-0-so-0-undefined-symbol-when-i-tried-ipython-pylab-in-ubuntu-1