# got "libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol" when I tried ipython --pylab in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, matplotlib, wxpython, enthought, canopy

I am currently using Ubuntu 13.10 and applied all the system updates. I have installed the Enthought Canopy (Version: 1.1.1.1452). And today when I tried to plot, I got nothing. After googling, I have run 'ipython --pylab' in command line but got the following message:

```
Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8
```

I could get into the interactive ipython shell but I still couldn't plot.

Then I follow the tips from user forum and I tried 'import wx' and got:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
```

Since I was able to use Canopy's plotting functionality a while ago, I suspect that Ubuntu's system update somehow introduces some library conflict with the current Canopy.

Anybody has a hint for me to solve this please? Thank you all very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem, same system (Ubuntu 13.10, Canopy 1.1.1.1452), this is what worked for me. According to [this](https://support.enthought.com/entries/22601196-wxPython) post, the problem is `wxPython` and `Canopy`:

> "We recommend that users who do not have a large wx-specific code base
>   use the Qt backend rather than wx."

Here's how you can do that specifically for getting `matplotlib` to work with Qt (and solve your problem). To find out which is your current backend use `matplotlib.get_backend()` by:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.get_backend()
'WXAgg'
```

If you are seeing `"WXAgg"` like above, [set the matplotlib backend](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html) to one of the known backends using `matplotlib.use()` as:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')
```

You can add the above in your script, or upon initializing a python session, and `pyplot`, `pylab` etc. would load without an error, for example:

```
import pylab  
from matplotlib import pylab                                       
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

**Update**:

A convenient way to configure the backend automatically is to edit the [matplotlibrc](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) configuration file. For Canopy the file is located in

`~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data`

In `matplotlibrc`, replace the line:

```
backend      : WXAgg
```

with:

```
backend      : Qt4Agg
```